# How to stop python Tkinter Entry Widget stretching in grid

Tags: python, tkinter

Used [GUI Builder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/spectcl/files/GUI%20Builder/2.5.20070129/) to generate the gui_ui.py file.
Problem is, when i write some text in the Entry Widget and then the Entry Widget itself stretches to hold the text, and it resized the whole window along with it.
The code,

```
    self._entry_2.grid(
        in_    = root,
        column = 2,
        row    = 1,
        columnspan = 1,
        ipadx = 0,
        ipady = 0,
        padx = 0,
        pady = 0,
        rowspan = 1,
        sticky = "ew"
    )
```

Grid is in two column, column1 has a label and column 2 has the entry widget. 
See the screenshots.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

I want it to always remain at size in first picture. 
How can i prevent it from auto resizing/stretching ?

Comment: I couldn't duplicate your issue using Tkinter - the text itself continues to grow but the entry box does not. And it looks like the latest version of GUI Builder for Mac is for PowerPC, so I could not try to duplicate it there. If you don't get an answer for this, you may want to try Tkinter itself (without GUI Builder).

Comment: spectcl itself is for ppc only, but the "GUI Builder" is the successor  of spectcl. Use this [download link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/spectcl/files/GUI%20Builder/2.5.20070129/guibuilder-macosx-universal-20070129/download), its universal (ppc and i386). Runs fine on my lion 10.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you set many attributes, but forgot `width`.

```
entry = Entry(parent, width=20)
```

Here is a [reference](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm).

Comment: Thanks,solved with `width = 20`, Previously it was
`self._entry_2 = Tkinter.Entry(root,
            width = 0,
        )`

Comment: Great, glad it helped (also thanks for the link to GUI Builder).